# Extract part of list

Tags: sorting

I have the following list:

```
{{{1, 0, 0}, {0.5, 1}}, {{2, 0, 0}, {0.5, 1}}, {{2, 0, 0}, {1, 1}}}
```

I would like to take the first part if the second part get a duplicate and if this duplicate is the minimum duplicate term of the list

I hope your understand my request:

The expected result is the following:

```
{{1, 0, 0},{1, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: Could you give your expected result in your post?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have edited my post ;)

Comment: This problem description has flaws.  Enhance your description and punctuation.

Comment: Sorry,I really don't know what you are after..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unclear and the OP has not provided feedback for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
L = {{{1, 0, 0}, {0.5, 1}}, {{2, 0, 0}, {0.5, 1}}, {{2, 0, 0}, {1, 1}}};
Replace[L[[All, 2]], Cases[Join[DeleteDuplicatesBy[L, Last], Tally[L[[All,
 2]]][[All, {2}]], 2], {a_, b_, c_} :> If[c =!= 1, b -> a, b -> Nothing]], {1}]
```

> {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}